# Excel VBA - apply conditional formatting formula to range

Tags: excel, vba

I need to highlight the cells in a range MyRange (i.e. B2:B30), where the value of the cell is <= 0 OR > 30).
With macro recorder, applying conditional formatting to a single cell, I got this:

```
Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=OR(O5<=0,O5>30)"
Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    .TintAndShade = 0.599963377788629
End With
Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
```

Is there a way to apply the formula to each cell of MyRange?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To apply the conditional formatting to B2:B30.

```
With Range("B2:B30")
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, _
        Formula1:="=AND(" & .Cells(1, 1).Address(0, 0) & "<>"""",OR(" & .Cells(1, 1).Address(0, 0) & "<=0," & .Cells(1, 1).Address(0, 0) & ">30))"
    .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0.599963377788629
    End With
    .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
End With
```

Comment: I can't replicate that error. Is the sheet protected? Is there anything in the range B2:B30?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  I translated the formula into Italian, I have that version of Excel. Now your code works but it highlights also empty cells as well as cells <= 0 OR > 30. How to tweak it so that it doesn't highlights empty cells?

Comment: Don't translate the formula. I'll update the answer to deal with empty cells.

Comment: It works great now, but I had to "translate" it into Italian Excel, otherwise I'd get the same error. It's actually strange because in VBA I just use "English" formulas.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?  The range is hardcoded here, do you need it to be dynamic?

```
Sub test()
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Range("B2:B30")
    
    With myRange
        .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=OR(O5<=0,O5>30)"
        .FormatConditions(.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
        With .FormatConditions(1).Interior
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
            .TintAndShade = 0.599963377788629
        End With
        .FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. The range is created by me, don't worry about that.
In the formula I see you used my example, with cell O5. I tried it, but it doesn't work: it highlights all the cells in the range regardless of their value.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the *out-of-the-box* `FormatConditions` *(`xlLessEqual` & `xlGreater`)* to slightly simplify without the need for formula. This is also more intuitive to read IMO

```
Sub Example()

'Declare & set variables
Dim ws As Worksheet, Target As Range
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
Set Target = ws.Range("B2:B30")

    'Delete existing formats, add new rules, apply formats
    With Target
        .FormatConditions.Delete
        .FormatConditions.Add xlCellValue, xlLessEqual, 0
        .FormatConditions.Add xlCellValue, xlGreater, 30
        .FormatConditions(1).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .FormatConditions(2).Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
    End With 

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Your code works but does the opposite of what I need.

Comment: So use `xlGreater` and `xlLess`. I read formula wrong my bad

Comment: @Dolphin975 - updated to correct for issue. Use the same method but make two rules and apply the format to each rule.